# I am working on An Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working an an Rails app. The problem I am have is when I cycle between my about and contact pages. I always get the error

> No route matches [GET] "/pages/pages/about"

or

> No route matches [GET] "/pages/pages/contact"

I'm trying  to change the routes my nav bar partial the tag  href to `"/about"` but the same error occur. it ask me to use the command rake routes and it shows

```
$ rake routes
    restaurants GET    /restaurants(.:format)          restaurants#index
                POST   /restaurants(.:format)          restaurants#create
 new_restaurant GET    /restaurants/new(.:format)      restaurants#new
edit_restaurant GET    /restaurants/:id/edit(.:format) restaurants#edit
     restaurant GET    /restaurants/:id(.:format)      restaurants#show
                PUT    /restaurants/:id(.:format)      restaurants#update
                DELETE /restaurants/:id(.:format)      restaurants#destroy
    pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)          pages#about
           root        /                               restaurants#index
  pages_contact GET    /pages/contact(.:format)        pages#contact"
```

can some one please help me!!

Comment: Please add your  `a`or `link_to` tags?

Comment: where exactly you are getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Your about and contact are under the url `/pages/about` and `/pages/contact` but the URL you are accessing is `/pages/pages/about` which doesn't exist.

You can see in the rake routes, the possible urls in the system.

you need to have the link in your web app as

```
<%= link_to 'About', pages_about_path %>

<%= link_to 'Contact', pages_contact_path %>
```

Comment: thanks for responding!  Where do the <%= link_to 'Contact', pages_contact_path %> tags go? like in my application.html or navbar partial>

Answer (score 0):

in your routes you can do something like

```
#config/routes.rb
ClientCruiser::Application.routes.draw do
  ....
  match "contact" => "pages#contact", :as => :contact, via: :all
  match "about" => "pages#about", :as => :about, via: :all
  ....
  root :to => 'pages#index'
end
```

The output of this

```
contact     /contact(.:format) pages#contact
  about     /about(.:format)   pages#about
   root GET /                  pages#index
```

the way you would make the call would be

```
<%= link_to about_path, "About", class: '' %>
<%= link_to contact_path, "Contact", class: '' %>
```